# Linux network stack queues

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I'm debugging some network driver under linux. In some place of this driver there is netif_stop_queue() function. It stops sending packets by kernel to my driver and it's ok.

I wonder how long kernel can queueing those packets until it starts to drop them? Is it the txqueuelen parameter in ifconfig which tell how many packets given interface may queue or there is yet another queue in kernel?

Comment: See such thing as a `Qdisc`. IIRC, it handles all the packets that goes to the device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "unsigned long tx_queue_len" field on net_device structure [netdevice.h, Line 1143](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/netdevice.h) controls the maximum number of frames that can be queued on the device's transmission queue

And yes, it is the same parameter in ifconfig. You can set the queue length with:

```
ifconfig <interface> txqueuelen <size>
Ex:
ifconfig eth0 txqueuelen 10000
```